# How to make an inner shadow effect on big font?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make the effect as demonstrate on this site http://dropshadow.webvex.limebits.com/ with arguments - `left:0` `top:0` `blur:1` `opacity:1` `examples:engraved` `font:sans serif`

I have tried css text-shadow with `#333333 -1px -1px` but seems not enough to make an inner shadow on such big font, it may be much more complex than i thought?

And worse is i'm using Cufon to replace the font but Cufon doesn't support blur of text-shadow

I guess maybe i should use JS to make this effect, but i doubt JS will work together with Cufon, or JS font replacement together with JS shadow maker?

Any ideas?

Comment: could it be a duplicate of this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css

Answer (score 0):

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/examples/text-shadow.html