# Is it possible to get cut out text effect like this using CSS/CSS3 only?

Tags: css

Is it possible to get cut out text effect like this using CSS/CSS3 only? or image is the only option to get this effect.

[image]

Comment: Not voting to close as a duplicate, because I don't know how closely it resembles what you want (and there's no definite answer there either) but this is a rather similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css

Comment: @David - Yes both questions are similar, should i close my question. or can i merge my question with the question u linked

Comment: well, if you say they're similar, I'll vote for a close, and if people agree, this will all be taken care of. no need for you to take action.

Comment: @David - Yes both questions are asking about almost same effect. I search "cut out text effect" before asking my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This should work:**
Here's a little trick I discovered using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements:

http://dabblet.com/gist/1609945

Answer (score 3):

`text-shadow` is your friend. [See this page](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/advanced-css-text-effects-web-typography-tips/) for lots of examples what you can achieve with it. Example #8 looks promising.

Comment: This will come in handy for me too someday! Thanks! +1

Comment: Answers should suggest code, not simply links. Links quickly die, and links-of-links die even faster, leaving good answers hollowed out like a big old dead tree.

Comment: @jerseyboy: I'm not going to replicate a 13 page web blog here.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Replicating a 13 page web blog would be unwise, but so is pointing to a page that isn't an original source.

Comment: @drinchev: Try Google. The new URL is http://jotarun.posterous.com/text-embossing-technique-with-css

Comment: @AaronDigulla *that* link is now dead too. Can't easily find an alternative on Google.

Comment: @ZachL: The original link (post #8 in my answer) works again. Or try Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20130326155518/http://jotarun.posterous.com/text-embossing-technique-with-css

Answer (score 2):

I found this
http://jsfiddle.net/NeqCC/

It supports white background and dark text

All credit goes to the creator

HTML

```
<!--
CSS3 inset text-shadow trick
Written down by Jyri Tuulos
http://about.me/jyrituulos

Effect originally found at http://timharford.com/
All credits for originality go to Finalised Design (http://finalisedesign.com/)

Note that this trick only works for darker text on solid light background.
-->
<h1 class="inset-text">Inset text-shadow trick</h1>
```

CSS

```
body {
    /* This has to be same as the text-shadows below */
    background: #def;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 6em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.inset-text {
    /* Shadows are visible under slightly transparent text color */
    color: rgba(10,60,150, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px #def, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 4px 6px #def;
}
/* Don't show shadows when selecting text */
::-moz-selection { background: #5af; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #5af; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really need for that particular effect is [`inset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#inset):

```
    text-shadow: inset #000 0 0 0.10em; /* THIS DOESN'T WORK */
```

[Unfortunately](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#ltshadowgt): "<shadow> is the same as defined for the ‘box-shadow’ property except that the ‘inset’ keyword is not allowed."

Comment: A very low level solution for this insanity sir is to get JavaScript (or semantic HTML) to make a transparent text on the center of the text (that willl be tricky) and then applying the shadow on that text ;) which will create pseudo realistic inset shadows ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text-shadow style to set a shadow for the top left corner. It will look close to what you are looking for, but as far as I know there is no way to do exactly what you are looking for in CSS/CSS3

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this effect with CSS and text, but it's a little insane. Basically you create a bunch of grey-zero css3 radial and linear gradients with a zero opacity and *carefully* position them over your text. But you'd be better off doing this in photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

A [slightly softer way](http://dabblet.com/gist/4040525) of using the pseudo-elements Web_Designer mentioned:

```
.depth {
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    color: black;
    font: bold 7em Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.depth:after {
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0px 0px 1.5px;
    content: attr(title);
    padding: 50px;
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px; 
    left: 1px;
}
```

It's a bit simpler - to get the soft rim of the depression you use the text-shadow of the :after pseudo and make it transparent, rather than using two pseudos. To my mind, it looks a lot cleaner too - it can work at much greater sizes. I've no idea how fast it is, though you'll probably be using text-shadow sparingly anyway.