# How to make text exactly like this?

Tags: css

How to make text exactly like this?
[image]

I tried this code

```
text-shadow: 0.3px 0.3px 1px #eef2f3, 0 0 0 #000, 0.3px 0.3px 1px #eef2f3;  z-index:400;
```

and it becomes like
[image]
I can never make it exactly the same no matter how I change the value,any advises?

Comment: Why don´t you just examine the original source code?

Comment: It is just a photoshop file

Comment: please post your complete code....

Comment: @FatDogMark: How do you know it is possible with CSS then?

Comment: Well, then examine the effects that were applied?

Comment: so thats actually not possible? I thought css can do many things

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968143/is-it-possible-to-get-cut-out-text-effect-like-this-using-css-css3-only) and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the text has an inner-shadow, this is pointing towards a graphics suite (Photoshop, Gimp, Corel, etc), unless there is a new flash or js library out there that adds inner shadows or gradients to text.

Using graphic suite, here are the steps to make text like this:

- Open Adobe Photoshop
- Create a the graphics desired with a mix of font, color, and styles
   -You can also spend this time creating hover/selected styles as well
- Export as a PNG-24 without a background (if you want to be able to use it on a variety of backgrounds.  If not, make sure your bkgnd color matches where it will be positioned)
- Add to your web page
- Pat yourself on the back for doing something awesome.