# make embossed text

Tags: css

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8859832/1252748) for making an embossed effect with text. Is this really the best way. Any new ideas on it. It just makes it impossible to work with if you have to add additional span tags to get the kerning right. I guess it adds extra nodes and messes up the pseudo selectors.

Comment: What about the other answers of that discussion? Have you tried them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use text shadow.

```
text-shadow{0px 1px 0px #fff, 0px -1px 0px #000}
```

This wont work in IE anything earlier than IE9 though.

Comment: compatibility's no problem. But the text shadow really looks like it's just got a shadow. It was looking for a shadow that's inset. To make it look like it's carved into the page

Comment: You can see http://www.caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow for compatibility and links to resources and online simulator (edit no inset keyword like box-shadow has)

Comment: you can just tweak the colours so they are similar to your colour scheme.

Comment: I found [this] (http://www.gordonhallart.com/blog/2011/04/27/creating-a-true-inset-text-effect-using-css3/) which is basically the effect I want, but on the lower right you can see the fuzzy shadow extending out of the text.

Comment: text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 0px -1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

Answer (score 1):

It's not, necessarily, cross-browser friendly, but there's always text-shadow, to emulate the embossed style.

```
h1.embossed {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xVTS3/).