# How do I make this beveled text effect with CSS?

Tags: css

Is there any way to give text this beveled look with only CSS?

[image: Beveled text image.]

To be clear, I'm looking for text that has thickness, but in a *beveled* way.  Not, for example, what you get with text-shadow, which seems to just [extend the edges of the font](http://markdotto.com/playground/3d-text/).

Comment: rather than how do i...? try something and if it fails, ask why is it....

Comment: I have searched for beveled text, 3d text, miscellaneous text effects, etc.  Nothing seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith ... I don't think that really helps...

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran: I don't understand how to get from an inner text shadow to the beveled appearance I'm looking for..?  (In fact, I don't see how text-shadow can help me at all, which is why all my Internet searches have been fruitless.)

Comment: @ladenedge: I thought this example from that same question would have helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889501/inner-text-shadow-with-css/17260716#17260716 But it won't give the complete beveled appearance of text that you are looking for.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NeqCC/ seems close

Comment: so i just saw this [codepen](http://codepen.io/giana/pen/LpwOpm?editors=010) and it reminded me of this post, although it's not quite the same and it's Firefox/Webkit only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, you cannot. The closest thing I've ever seen is the inset text-shadow trick mentioned in the comments and I haven't seen anything online that answers this either.

I'm assuming that SEO and accessibility are the reasons to keep this strictly as an HTML/CSS separation, though. This effect may be able to be accomplished via an img tag with a corresponding alt attribute (simple solution) or by using SVG (for selectable and scalable text) with the appropriate fallback(s). Also, if you're looking for flowing/wrapping text, SVG might be able to handle that as well. Check this answer for more details: [Auto line-wrapping in SVG text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text)

Answer (score 1):

Here, play around with the numbers until you get a satisfying result.

```
.inset {

color: rgba(10,60,150, 0.8);
text-shadow: 3px 4px 6px #def, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 4px 6px #def;
}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/yYGRBP

Comment: I really appreciate your answer (especially considering all the downvotes), but I'm afraid I don't see how to bring 3d text inset (examples of which are all over the Internet) into an *angled 3d outset* (of which I can find no example anywhere).

Comment: It is best to do it in photoshop etc, or to find a web font somewhere.
This comes close to the one you posted: http://www.1001fonts.com/facets-nf-font.html

Comment: @Damianocelent Why not Blender