# How to stop `-webkit-background-clip: text` making text thinner?

Tags: css, webkit

### Problem

Text is displayed imperfectly, when `-webkit-background-clip: text` is used.

### Screenshot

[image: The first four words are too thin.]

### Code

```css
body {
  background: black !important;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 200;
}

span {
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<span>The first four words</span> are too thin.
```

### Important

1. The perceived attributes should not be changed by the solution. (I.e. black background, white text, thin font etc.)
2. The solution should work well in other cases too. (E.g. red background, blue text, thick font etc.)
3. There should be no side-effects. (E.g text becoming blurry or too thick etc.)

| Approach | Problem |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| increase `font-weight` | Makes the text blurry. | `filter: custom(…)` |
| add `-webkit-text-stroke` | Makes the text too thick. | semi-transparency |
| add `text-shadow` | Makes the text blurry. | multiple shadows |
| increase `font-size` | Should look the same. | `transform: scale(0.5)` |
| change the `font-family` | Should look the same. | `src: url(Roboto.svg)` |
| change the `background-color` | Should look the same. | `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` |
| change the `color` | Should look the same. | `filter: saturate(0)` |
| `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` | Useless. | - |
| `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` | Useless. | - |
| `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` | Useless. | - |
| bug report (find&vote, or [create](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)) | Not an instant solution. | draw attention |

### Goal

To fix the `-webkit-background-clip: text`, preferably by adding a simple CSS declaration.
(JavaScript or other approaches might be useable as well.)

Comment: Should it be reported at [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry)?

Comment: i do not think so, because the bug occurs on other browsers as well

Comment: this isn't a bug, coloring text using background is not the same algorithm as with using color

Comment: @HaveProblemsEveryday: You are right. (I've tested now in Edge.) All the WebKit based browsers are affected, I guess. Should it be reported at [webkit.org](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/), then?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Not the same algorithm, that's true. What if a new JavaScript engine used a different algorithm to calculate `2 + 2`, and the result was `5`? Would that be a bug? Not the same algorithm, that's true. But is the result incorrect? Both of the CSS methods above ask for the same result: display the text as white, thin Roboto. The WebKit declaration has an unwanted side-effect, do you agree?

Comment: (This quote from [/a/7938200/1293492](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938200/1293492) might be relevant: "Perhaps someone should recommend that the W3C add **background-clip: reverse-text**, that would cut a mask through the background instead of cutting the background to fit inside the text.")

Comment: not the same algorithm AND not the same result. I didn't say a different algorithm for the same resutl.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Should the result of the `background-clip` method be the same as of the `color` method?